# How do I display the notification when the item is added or not added succesfully using AJAX and PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I got stuck in my code because I can't display the notification when the item is added successfully or not. How do I display it using ajax and php?

This div will display the notification but I find it hard to solve because it is in the other php file:

```
<center><div class="notify"></div></center>
```

Code for ajax:

```
dialog = $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
      buttons: {
        "Add": function() {
                    var reg=$("#registration-form").valid();
                    if(reg==false){
                        $('#registration-form .submit').click();
                    }
                    else if(reg==true){

                        var product_code = $("#product_code_txt").val();
                        var product = $("#product_name_txt").val();
                        var unit = $("#unit_txt").val();  
                        var quantity = $("#quantity_txt").val();   
                        var c_price = $("#c_price_txt").val();   
                        var s_price = $("#s_price_txt").val();   
                        var date = $(".date_txt").val();   
                        var cat_id = $("#drpdown").val();
                        $.ajax({
                                type: "POST",
                                url: "getAddMedicine.php",
                                data: {product_code_txt: product_code, product_name_txt: product, unit_txt: unit, quantity_txt: quantity, c_price_txt: c_price, s_price_txt: s_price, date_txt: date, category_txt: cat_id},
                                success: function(html){
                                    $(".displayData").load("getMedicine.php");
                                    dialog.dialog("close");
                                }
                            });
                        return false;
                    }
        },
        Cancel: function() {
          dialog.dialog( "close" );
        }
      },
```

Code for insertng into the database:

```
<?php   
        $product_code=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['product_code_txt']);
        $check="Call checkMedicine('$product_code')";       

        $result=mysqli_query($conn, $check);
        $rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result);

        if($rowcount==0){
            include("db.php");
            $product_code=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['product_code_txt']);
            $product=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['product_name_txt']);
            $cat_id=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['category_txt']);
            $unit=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['unit_txt']);

            $date=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['date_txt']);
            $quantity=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['quantity_txt']);

            $s_price=number_format($_POST['s_price_txt'], 2);
            $s_price=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $s_price);

            $c_price=number_format($_POST['c_price_txt'], 2);
            $c_price=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $c_price);

            $sql = "Call addMedicine('$product_code','$product','$unit','$quantity','$c_price','$s_price','$date','$cat_id')";      

            if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
                echo "1"; //how to display it into the div
            } else {
                echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
            }       
        }
        else
            echo "2"; //how to display it into the div  
    mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

In the `success` function, the `html` argument is the reponse from the `php` page. Use it to set your notification like this:

```
success: function(html){
  $(".displayData").load("getMedicine.php");
  $('. notify').html(html); // add this line
  dialog.dialog("close");
},
```

If you want to do more than that like show the notification in a different color, you'll need to add the html in the response before sending

Comment: how to get the value if the `echo "1";` and then i'll pass it into a javascript variable. e.g `var notify=$(".notify").html(html);`

Comment: If I understand, you would want `notify=$(".notify").html();` there

Comment: I want to get its value and store it into the notify variable.  `var notify = $(".notify").html(html).val();` the problem is I can't get the value.

Comment: @HelpMe what `value` do you mean? your php returns "Item added successfully" or an error message, are you saying you want the php to return both the inserted value and the "Item added successfully" message or error?

Comment: Yes I want to return the value "Item added successfully". I just want tell you that I edited the echo "Item added successfully" to echo "1".

Comment: Im not sure I fully understand, are you wanting to return 2 different values, or just the one value but also use it elsewhere in your javascript?

Comment: yes I want to return the `echo "1"` and send it to the `var notify`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107448/discussion-between-help-me-and-delightedd0d).